# "Compile pdf" in Rstudio works but knit2pdf does not work in R or RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, pdflatex, miktex

I'm hoping someone can point me to the internal setting that can fix my issue with compiling tex docs from R.

My issues is that `texi2pdf` and `knit2pdf` throw warnings and do not generate a pdf.

I can get Rnw files to compile using the "Compile pdf" button in RStudio, I can knit rnw files into text files, and I can get my tex files to compile into pdf using TeXnicCenter, but I can't get the `texi2pdf` or `knit2pdf` functions to work in R.

In Windows 7 on one machine with TexLive installed and on another machine with MikTex 2.9 installed, when I run the following:

```
library(knitr)
f = system.file("examples", "knitr-minimal.Rnw", package = "knitr")
knit(f)  # compile to tex
texi2pdf(gsub('Rnw', 'tex', f))
```

the first part works (rnw->tex), but the texi2pdf (tex->pdf) results in:

```
Warning message:
running command '"C:\PROGRA~2\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe" --quiet --pdf 
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/knitr/examples/knitr-minimal.tex" --max-
iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I 
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1
```

The same is true if I run `knit2pdf(f)`, I get the same warning message + a pop up "pdflatex.EXE has stopped working".

One other thing I don't understand is that I have MikTex 2.9 in my path, but the warning message references MikTex 1.9, which is not installed on my machine and is not in the path.

Comment: That's a bug imho. I also get the output of `Sys.which("texify")` to be the exact same path, and there's no distribution to be found there.

Comment: Do you think that's what's causing the compilation problems? I don't understand the interworkings of these pieces, is that a bug with r? knitr? tools?

Comment: It's not a bug, and it's not looking for MikTex 1.9. I was horribly wrong about that. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/texi2pdf-doesn-t-find-the-correct-MikTex-installation-due-to-erroneous-Sys-which-td4740439.html

Comment: The Same error is happening to me. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a fix as a work around...

```
library(knitr)
setwd(system.file("examples", package = "knitr"))
knit("knitr-minimal.Rnw")  # compile to tex
system('pdflatex knitr-minimal.tex')
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, and it seems it was because MikTex 2.9 was installed under my User account. R is also installed under my User account. Here is what worked for me:

1. Uninstall MikTex and reinstall it under Program files. Update MikTex from its console.
2. Add "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64" to Windows PATH (delete the old MikTex path).
3. Restart you computer
4. Uninstall and reinstall the knitr package (that might not be necessary).